# Cannot install Beautiful Soup in Anaconda Python 3.6.4 Windows 10

Tags: python

I install Beautiful Soup in Anaconda Python 3.6.4 Windows 10:

1. I downloaded and unpacked `beautifulsoup4-4.6.3.tar.gz` on my Desktop
2. I created an environment variable `Pythonbasepath` including the following directories:

   - C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Anaconda3
   - C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Anaconda3\Lib
   - C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Anaconda3\include
   - C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Anaconda3\DLLs
   - C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Anaconda3\Scripts
   - C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
3. From the directory where I have extracted Beautiful Soup I try to run a command and I get an error:

> C:\Users\Mika and Friends\Desktop\bs4\bs4>python setup.py install
>   'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

It seems something is wrong with the environment variable setup, but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following command from Command Prompt:

`conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4`

This is the easiest way to install a python library in Anaconda.

Comment: As of [2020-02-26](https://github.com/conda-forge/beautifulsoup4-feedstock/commit/00ea1787a4f2db2473cb1d8c64beb9a14e95be26), you **can** now use [`conda install bs4`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/bs4), which installs a meta package that just depends directly on `beautifulsoup4`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of installing bs4 package was resolved in the following way:

bs4 is not a package that is available through "standard" channel. By that I mean I could not install it by issuing the command "conda instal bs4". Instead the package can be installed by issuing the command "python setup.py install". To be able to issue that command two things should be done.

1) Make Python to run from the command line. If you have a few python environment then find out a path to python.exe of that envrieonment and add that path to the environmental variables:
- To find out the path to python.exe open Anaconda prompt and choose an ppropriate environment (In my case, when I run Anaconda prompt I am in "base" environment and I can switch to my another environment "tensorflow" by issuing command "activate tensorflow")
-One in the appropriate environment you issue the following commands: python (to run python); then import sys; then sys.executable => you will see the path to python.exe of the environment where you want to install bs4. So we know the path to python.exe.

- Go to Control panel then System then Advanced Settings then Choose Enviromental variables then add the path to your python.exe to the "PATH" variable (to system "PATH" or User "PATH": I added to user PATH so it works for a specific user)\
- So after this steps python.exe should be running from a command prompt. To check that do the following: Run command prompt (cmd) and type python => python should run from any folder.

2) Download and unpack bs4. 
- One can download bs4 from here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/.

- Unpack it and from the location of the unpacked bs4 package run the command "python setup.py install" from the command prompt:
- got to the floder with the unpacked bs4 and press "Sgift+Right-click" and choose "Open Command window/Open PowerShell window" (depending whether you have Windows 7/10). At the command prompt type "python setup.py install". You should see quick installation of bs4. (Note: setup.py is a file that comes with bs4 package and it should be in the directory where you saved unpacked bs4)
- To check that you have bs4 package installed run command "conda list" from the Anaconda prompt of the environment where you wanted to install bs4. You should see beutifulsoup4 (if you installed bs4). Another way to see that everything is working is be able to impport BeutifulSoup class from bs4 when you issue the statement in your code "from bs4 import BeutifulSoup as bs".

Thank you.

Argyn

Comment: _bs4 is not a package that is available through "standard" channel. By that I mean I could not install it by issuing the command "conda instal bs4"._ That's because the package is called `beautifulsoup4`, there's nothing more to it.

Comment: To address the common confusion between the package and project names, the [`bs4` meta package](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/) was created (in 2016), but that was not available on conda at the time of this question or answer. However, as of [2020-02-26](https://github.com/conda-forge/beautifulsoup4-feedstock/commit/00ea1787a4f2db2473cb1d8c64beb9a14e95be26), you **can** now use [`conda install bs4`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/bs4), a meta package that just depends directly on `beautifulsoup4`.

Answer (score -2):

One method that happened to work, and I am not sure how valid (safe) it is for other users:
I use Miniconda (smaller Anaconda packages) and installed bs4 through `pip install bs4` instead of `conda install bs4` (because it doesn't exist) in terminal whilst using my personal conda env to run a python program using BeautifulSoup. May save some trouble for others, but could be due to other settings on my device. 
I was using conda 4.8.3, Python 3.7.6, Windows 10 when this worked for me.

Comment: _I use Miniconda (smaller Anaconda packages) and installed bs4 through `pip install bs4` instead of `conda install bs4` (because it doesn't exist)_ The package is called beautifulsoup4, not bs4. Be careful when using pip inside of Conda environments, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: At the time of this answer the [`bs4` meta package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/bs4) did in fact exist. It was added [a month before](https://github.com/conda-forge/beautifulsoup4-feedstock/commit/00ea1787a4f2db2473cb1d8c64beb9a14e95be26).